# PHP foreach to make query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array like this

```
Array ( [12313] => 1 [12312] => 1 ) 1
```

The array keys are the items that exist in the warehouse and values are the number of items.

I would like to check if the items and amounts actually exist in the warehouse database using php. I thought maybe I could use a foreach for each item check but I don't know how to use foreach. I would like to make a query like:

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as amount FROM warehouse where item=12313");
$check=$query->row_array();
$amt=$check['amount'];
if($amt>0){
   return true;
}
else{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: are those solution really works for you? make value of 12312=>0 and check what happens

Comment: all the solution checks only the first item has minimum one data

Comment: I will replace inner codes with working code. The code in the question is just a description. The main solution i would like to get is how to use key and value of array in foreachloop.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array=array ( '12313' => 1,'12312' => 1 );
foreach($array as $k=>$val)
{
  $query=$this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as amount FROM warehouse where item='".$k."'");
  $check=$query->row_array();
  $amt=$check['amount'];
  if($amt>0){
    return true;
  }
  else{
   return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your query should be encapsulated with Double quotes....And wrap $k  with single quote bcz if it will work for both string as well as int.... and while selecting metion amount not all *

Comment: why the foreach loop?it will query only for 12312 and return true or false.will not do anything for 12312

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like:

```
$items = array(
        12313 => 1,
        12312 => 1,
    );

foreach ( $items as $key => $value ) : //iterate over array
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as amount FROM warehouse where item = $key";
    $check = $query->row_array();
    $amt = $check['amount'];
    if( $amt>0 ) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
$arr = array("[12313]" => "1" ,"[12312]" => "2");
foreach ($arr as  $key=>$value) {
$query="SELECT COUNT(*) as amount FROM warehouse where item='".$key."'";
$check=$query->row_array();
$amt=$check['amount'];
if($amt>0){
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: @user3789191 let me know if it is working for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $array = array('12313' => 1, '12312' => 1);
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

                $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as amount');
                $this->db->from('warehouse');
                $this->db->where('item', $key);
                $result = $this->db->get()->row_array();

                return ($result['amount'] >= $value) ? TRUE : FALSE; //match no of items
             // return ($result['amount'] > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE; //OR if just check the count
            }
```